# how to put afterpage inside environment definition?

Tags: environments, afterpage

if i used `\afterpage` outside the my custom environment, it works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum, afterpage}
\newenvironment{myenv}{

  some macros that manipulate page numbering

} {

  another macros here

}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]

\afterpage{
  \begin{myenv}
    \lipsum[3]
  \end{myenv}
}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

i want to put the macro `\afterpage` inside the definition of the environment. i understand that this is necessary to use the macro `\NewEnviron` from the package `environ`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum, afterpage, environ}
\NewEnviron{myenv}{
  \afterpage{
  some macros that manipulate page numbering

\BODY

  another macros here
  }
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]

\begin{myenv}
  \lipsum[3]
\end{myenv}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

but i get the error:

> ```
> $ pdflatex my.latex
> ...
> ! Undefined control sequence.
> \AP@ ...that manipulate page numbering \par \BODY 
>                                                   \par another macros here \...
> l.20 \lipsum[2]
> ```

Comment: `! Undefined control sequence. \arterpage ` are you sure this is not a typo?

Comment: @clemens, you are right, a typo there, but after its correction, only changed an error message.

Comment: @Werner, 1. file `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/environ/environ.sty` is from debian package `texlive-latex-extra-2012.20120611-2`, and contains text:  `2008/06/18 v0.2`. 2. the same error when using file from `texlive-latex-extra-2014.20141024-1`, that contains text: `2014/05/04 v0.3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to put the token `\BODY` into afterpage you want to put all the tokens from the current environment so

```
\def\afterpagebody#1{%
\afterpage{%%
  some macros that manipulate page numbering%%
   #1%
  another macros here%
  }}

\NewEnviron{myenv}{%%
  \expandafter\afterpagebody\expandafter{\BODY}%%
}
```

I hope you read the warnings in the `afterpage` documentation before using it in production:-)

Answer (score 1):

`\BODY` is not visible on the page that follows your `myenv` environment, hence the "Undefined control sequence" error. It is only available within `myenv`. To avoid complications with `\BODY`'s accessibility, you can store it in another variable:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{afterpage,environ}

\newcounter{myenvcntr}
\NewEnviron{myenv}{%
  \stepcounter{myenvcntr}%
  \expandafter\global\expandafter\let\csname BODY@\themyenvcntr\endcsname\BODY
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\afterpage{\noexpand\setcounter{myenvcntr}{\themyenvcntr}}}\x
  \afterpage{%
  some macros that manipulate page numbering

  \csname BODY@\themyenvcntr\endcsname

  another macros here
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]

\begin{myenv}
This is some text in \texttt{myenv}. \lipsum[1]
\end{myenv}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

The above method stores `\BODY` inside `\BODY@<num>`, where `<num>` is incremented in case you do multiple `myenv`s on the same page.

Be careful about [spurious spaces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764) in your definitions.

Comment: What happens if myenvcntr get incremented twice on the same page?