# Page orientation to horizontal

Tags: tables

I am new user of LaTeX and currently I am writing a thesis in which I have to add large table. I successfully did it through below written code. But, as I added my table horizontally, In the PDF, the user has to rotate the page in order the view it. Is other any way to change orientation of only this page, not the table?

```
\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{ yy}
\label{xx}

xyz

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

Comment: see the code in the answer here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344065/combining-command-command-and-beginenvironment-endenvironment-in-newe/344066#344066 (this is possibly a duplicate question)

Comment: I think you are looking for the `pdflscape` package. Try: `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{pdflscape}\begin{document}hello world\begin{landscape}hello world\end{landscape}\end{document}`.

Comment: Any case: your code example does not make much sense as you have multiple `\centering`s and a `table` inside your `sidewaystable`. You intended something like: `\begin{sidewaystable}\centering\begin{tabular}{c}xyz\end{tabular}\caption{yy}\label{xx}\end{sidewaystable}`, right? (and of course invoking the `rotating` package in the preamble)